# javascript new window location parameter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

javascript `window.open` parameter `location` does not work.

I do not want to show address bar in the new window.

jsbin example - http://jsbin.com/ucusiq/1/edit

Comment: try showing a popup instead

Comment: I didn't get it. Did you mean html popup. I cannot use that in my project. I want new window with no address bar. Please check my jsbin link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mram888 is right. Show it as a popup. Use a script on the lines of the following:

`window.open('/location.html','windowName','directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350');`

Comment: I tried ur solution but it did not work. Please check this link - http://jsbin.com/ucusiq/1/edit. Please let me know if possible what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Different browser has different implementation. Most of browser doesn't support this feature right now for some reasons. If you insist of this, i would suggest that you use GeckoFX(a mozilla engine) to create your own browser.

Comment: After double checking, it has been cleared up that what you're trying to do cannot be done as it is a security risk, hiding an address bar from the user can be used to trick them into browsing to malicious sites where there credentials could be stolen. It has been stated by all browsers that such scripts, as the one I posted are simply ignored.